# Issue with content security policy on Angular app

Tags: angular, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, content-security-policy

I was working on my angular project. suddenly all my outputs are vanished and console is flooded with errors. some what i reduced the error with CSP meta tags but still it is not rectified. I am getting a result of Cannot get / and these are the following error left in my console which is stopping my app.

```
5645ad61-4cf9-4577-9739-0269cce67fa6:110  - Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-l7otoeLhnuXtvcAJGSPybnAM55G1LN6Ox3i/VSelamA='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback

Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.

Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:4200/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
```

**My Meta Tag **

```
<meta http-equiv="content-security-policy" content="sandbox; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self' ; script-src 'sha256-l7otoeLhnuXtvcAJGSPybnAM55G1LN6Ox3i/VSelamA='; connect-src 'self';" />
```

Comment: "Unchecked runtime.lastError" is a message from an extension so maybe it's broken. Try disabling it, the id should be shown in the error source or call stack.